# Allow cookies in Chrome for local path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I prefer to work in Google Chrome but it doesn't save my cookies of a project I'm working on right now.
When I open the (local) path in Safari the cookies will be stored correctly but Chrome doesn't save them.
How do I allow cookies of projects directly accessed from my hard-drive? Adding the exact local path to Chromes cookie settings won't work.

I thought about something like `files:///[*]`, but it wouldn't work out for me.